# Identify "decoupling sites" in glucose oxydase reaction

Tags: biochemistry

> Given the following coupled reactions:
>   $$\ce{glucose + O2 + H2O + glucose~oxydase -> gluconic~acid + H2O2}$$
>   $$\ce{H2O2 + TMB(star) -> TMB}$$
>
> Identify:
>
> 1. A potential reagent or product that could act as a decoupling site leading to a falsely **high** glucose concentration.
> 2. A potential reagent or product that could act as a decoupling site leading to a falsely **low** glucose concentration.

Note: The second reaction is just hydrogen peroxide reacting with $\ce{3,3',5,5'-Tetramethylbenzidine}$, to form the more absorbent version (I can't remember if it's reduced or oxidized).

The experiment involves running the above reaction on a sample with an unknown amount of glucose, then running the sample through a spectrometer to determine the absorbance and thus the concentration of glucose.

The only thing I can think of is that if the sample warmed up too much you might lose some of the oxygen, resulting in a lower than expected glucose measurement. Though you'd have to lose enough oxygen for it to become the limiting reactant, which I don't see as being too plausible.

I can't find anything anywhere else and I'm stumped.